# HTML tags in php email

Tags: php, html, email, html-email

I want to send email in php with some HTML.
In my email, it's giving me like,

```
Hello <strong>,</strong><br><br>
```

It's not basically parse HTML code. Instead of effect, it's printing html tags.

This is my email function:

```
mail("$user_email","ESubject","$message","From: Name");
```

Message variable:

```
$message = "Hello <strong>,</strong><br><br>
        To verify your email and complete your registration please click on the link below: <br /><br />
        <a href='<?=$link?>'>VERIFY ACCOUNT</a>";
```

Comment: If you're looking to send anything other than the simplest of mails, your best bet it to pick up a library such as Swift Mailer or PHP Mailer.  It seems very simple initially, but as soon as you get into the world of multi-part mails, attachments and suchlike you'll find yourself writing a lot of code you really don't need to - and then finding a lot of your mails get caught in spam folders.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the `Content type : text/html` on your header !

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
```

and add it to your `mail()`

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); //<--- Like that.
```

**Note:**
If intending to send HTML or otherwise Complex mails, it is recommended to use the PEAR package » [`PEAR::Mail_Mime`](http://pear.php.net/package/Mail_Mime).

[`Source : PHP.net`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php)

---

**`EDIT :`**

Just do it this way

```
$message = "Hello <strong>,</strong><br><br>
        To verify your email and complete your registration please click on the link below: <br /><br />
        <a href=$link>VERIFY ACCOUNT</a>";
```

Comment: Do I need to pass header variable in mail function

Comment: Yes ofcourse. You have to. See the link I had provided. It gives you a clear-cut understanding. _Especially see the example #4_

Comment: I am able to pass html form. But, the problem is it's not passing php variable now..

Comment: Can you post the attempts on your question so we can have a look ?

Comment: I have edited `$message` variable.. I am not getting link variable as href.

Comment: oh.. sorry.. It was silly mistake..

Answer (score 2):

For better understanding please refer below script:

```
 <?php
    $to = "somebody@example.com, somebodyelse@example.com";
    $subject = "HTML email";

    $message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>HTML email</title>
    </head>
    <body>Hello <strong>,</strong><br><br>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";

    // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
    $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

    // More headers
    $headers .= 'From: <webmaster@example.com>' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
    ?>
```